# Switching year columns to one column in Python Eurostat

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large dataset from Eurostat. I am trying to move all year columns 1960-2019 to a single column called "year". How can I do this?

A sample of the data:

```
unit    sex age geo\time    2019    2018    2017    2016    2015    2014    ... 1969    1968    1967 1960

0   NR  F   TOTAL   AD  37388.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN

1   NR  F   TOTAL   AL  1432833.0   1431715.0   1423050.0   1417141.0   1424597.0   1430827.0   ... NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Read it to pandas dataframe and use melt.

Comment: Thanks @Pramote, melt has worked well! However, is there a way to include the years in a range rather than write down each one by one? I would like to include the years 1990-2019 CODE: demo_pjangroup = pd.melt(demo_pjangroup, id_vars=['geo', 'geo_full', 'sex', 'age'], value_vars=[2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990])

Comment: @Magdalena you can use `range(2019,1989,-1)` instead of the complete list to get a list of years from 2019 to 1990.

Comment: @S.Au.Ra.B.H I'm afraid this does not work, getting a KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported when running CODE: demo_pjangroup = pd.melt(demo_pjangroup, id_vars=['geo_full', 'geo', 'sex', 'age'], value_vars=[range(2019,1989,-1)])

Comment: Ah. I think either `value_vars=range(2019,1989,-1)` or `value_vars=[*range(2019,1989,-1)]` should work.

Comment: @S.Au.Ra.B.H Many thanks, just for completion value_vars=range(2019,1989,-1) worked well!